# Mapping properties to lambdas instead of using factory method/pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm receiving a JSON object which has many properties and the properties change (properties are added/removed) according to the type of the data in the JSON object. I'm expecting to receive many different types of data. Each property in the JSON needs a type of formatting.

Example:

```
// objectA
{
  property1: 10
  type: "money"
}
// objectB
{
  property2: 10
  type: "quantity"
}
// objectC
{ 
  property1: 10
  property2: 10
  type: "ingredient"
}
```

Result:

```
 // objectA
 {
   property1: "$10.00"
   type: "money"
 }
 // objectB
 {
   property2: "10"
   type: "quantity"
 }
 // objectC
 { 
   property1: "$10.00"
   property2: "10"
   type: "ingredient"
 }
```

What I have in mind is the following: I'd format all properties that I can find and strip off the null values. I thought this would be less cumbersome than creating the factory pattern, thus avoiding creating 10 sub-classes.

Is this feasible in Java? These are the steps I'd like to follow:

1. Add a Map <property.enum, function> (functions are lambda I guess);
2. Iterate over all JSON properties;
3. Check if the property exists in my Map

   - If exists, execute the function and map to the new return object
   - If it doesn't, do not add to the new return object

With the factory method I'd have to create one `transformTo()` method for each type which seems overkill for this scenario. Is this a common pattern? I've never heard of it if so...

Comment: To clarify, are you transforming the input JSON to an output JSON, or are you binding the JSON to Java objects?

Comment: why stripping the nulls ?  Isn’t an information 0 very different from the absence of information ?

Comment: Unfortunately the JSON object was stored in one Object field in one class and the output is a JSON format.

Comment: I wouldn't remove 0, only nulls because it means the value doesn't exist in the representation they have